# converting column to string from object to avoid pandas dataframe.to_hdf complaining about mixed type

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, hdfs

I am reading a CSV file from an external source and attempting to save it as an 
hdfs file using pandas.to_hdf() function.  I load the csv file into a pandas dataframe, do some massaging, then call the to_hdf method.
When calling the to_hdf() function, the following exception occurs:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 902, in to_hdf
    return pytables.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 267, in to_hdf
    f(store)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 262, in <lambda>
    f = lambda store: store.put(key, value, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 810, in put
    self._write_to_group(key, value, append=append, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1259, in _write_to_group
    s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3751, in write
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3433, in create_axes
    raise e
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [item_id] because
its data contents are [mixed-integer] object dtype
```

item_id isn't actually a column, it's part of a multi-index that i set after loading the dataframe. when i print the types of the index, i see:

```
>>> df.index.dtype
dtype('O')
```

I am trying to figure out how to convert this item_id index to a string.  i have also tried setting changing the type to a string type prior to setting the index by doing all of the following, but the type remains object:

```
df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].astype('str') # doesn't work
df['item_id'] = df['item_id'].astype(str) # doesn't work
```

without know much, my gut is that pandas simply stores strings as objects.  if so, how can i get the to_hdf function to treat it as a string?

**UPDATE:**

What i failed to mention above is that prior to calling the to_hdf method, i was doing a pandas.concat to merge two files. The first file had ids that were all numeric, so the read_csv function must have inferred an int type for that dataframe.  the second file had mixed int + string ids, so the read_csv must have inferred string or object.   I would have thought that pd.concat would have converted the entire column to string, but i'm guessing not.  to solve my issue, i do the following before calling to_hdf:

```
df["item_id"] = df["item_id"].map(str).map(str.strip)
```

Comment: Can you call the python built-in `type()` on one of these elements (`type(element)`) that has `dtype('O')` -- It doesn't look like numpy knows it's a string.

Comment: you mean like:  type(df.index.values[0])?  if so i get back "<type 'tuple'>".
the value is :  ('001602 ', Timestamp('2015-03-10 00:00:00'))

Comment: Have you tried not using an index when you read the CSV file?  Or if you need an index to do your interim work, copying the index to a new column and then calling `.reset_index()`?

Comment: yes, i don't initially use an index. i set it later.  but i think i might have figured out a solution.  I left out one key piece of info i think..which is that i was loading two csv files in to dataframes, and concatenating them.  I'm would think that pandas.concat would convert the types to string (though i'm not sure why i thought that..in thinking about it, it probably can't make that determination and simply wraps the items in object).

Comment: When Pandas says you have a column containing type as Object, that likely means you have mixed-types within your column.  The fact that this changes when you concatenate would indicate you are mixing your types at this point.